# android read from attrtibutes file in Activity

Tags: android

I have an attribute file with content like this -

```
<declare-styleable name="MessagingFragment">
        <attr name="favouritePageTitle" format="string" />
        <attr name="chatPageTitle" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

I want to read from activity xml and use it in MyActivity. How can i do this

Comment: Which type of your attribute file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/) what you are looking for?

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
R.styleable.MyCustomWidget);

String myText = a.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomWidget_myText);
```